# Can i have ubuntu 15.10 with linux kernel of 3.14

Tags: kernel, 15.10

I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed in my system with kernel  of 4.2, I want to know can i change the kernel of it to 3.14 without any serious problem such as hardware or graphically problems or any security weakness ?

p.s. My laptop is N56VM-A

Answer (score -1):

You could use any version of kernel if you want.
Here are two ways. Pick up one of them is enough:

A. use apt to install kernels for you.

B. manually install mainline kernels by dpkg

Steps for A:

1. command in terminal: apt-cache search linux-image
2. you will see the kernel list. pick up the one you want. For example,

   linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic
3. command in terminal: sudo apt-get install . For example,

   sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic
4. reboot the system once the installation of apt is done. That is!

Steps for B:

1. go to here http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
2. pick up the kernel version you want
3. download those kernel *.deb you want
4. install the *.deb you just downloaded by

   sudo dpkg -i *.deb

(optional) you might want to use [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fourdollars/scripts/master/ubuntu/mainline-kernels.sh) to help to download those *.deb

Comment: so there won't be any hardware or graphically problem or security weakness ?

Comment: That question should have been part of the original question. Also add in about what hardware you are talking.

Comment: @Rinzwind, tnx for your supervision :)

Comment: graphically problem? Maybe, but I can not answer you because this is a hardware- and kernel- depended questions.

security weakness? Every kernel has its known and unknown security weakness ; ) Once the known security issue is found, it will be fixed very soon. This is the advantage of FOSS (free and open source software)

So, please prepare a restore media (which could be a live usb stick, for example) before you use another kernel. I will suggest do not remove the original kernel you used for a while.

Comment: In Ubuntu, if you change your kernel according to my steps of both of the two approaches, grub will update grub menu and reserve the original kernels. Thus, please feel free to change the kernel. If you have issues like failing to boot, just stop at the grub menu and select your original kernel to boot.

Comment: @tai271828 tnx you so much ...